# Error while launching launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on porting a driver from fuerte to indigo.  The driver I'm trying to launch is this one:
https://github.com/udmamrl/NovAtel_dgps_driver

I've been following this tutorial, http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild and I think I've got most of them ready except I'm still encountering some issues. Every time I'm trying to launch a file, I get this error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [NovAtel_dgps_driver/NovAtel_dgps_driverV2.py]: NovAtel_dgps_driver
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

I'm still fairly new to ROS and I'm not sure what to do next

**EDIT 1**

Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more, what do you mean by setting up by work space correctly ?

**EDIT 2**

Yeah I've been working through them and I thought I had them down. This is the output of $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

/home//catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213658/error-while-launching-launch-file/) by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-14**:
have you followed all the steps in the tutorial at http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace?
Can you please post the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

**Comment by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on 2015-07-14**:
Yeah I've been working through them and I thought I had them down. This is the output of $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

/home//catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-15**:
alright, so your path seems to be correct.
Do you have a link to the source code?
Otherwise, it will be hard to track the error down.

Other ideas (but just guesses): is the `.py` executable? does `roscd ...` bring you to the correct folder? is the name of the type and pkg in the launch file correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you set up your workspace layout correctly?

As you can see from your error message, the paths that ROS is trying to find the executable are all within `/opt/ros/indigo`. So if you have your driver somewhere else (e.g. in `/home/<USERNAME>/catkin_ws/src`, it will not be found.

To set up your workspace, follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). And remember to source the `<CATKIN_WS>/devel/setup.bash` file in each terminal you want to use ROS in, or append it to your `.bashrc`.

Check if your path can be found by ROS by examining the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1